# Attribute routing with http PUT method constraint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

I'm using the new attribute routing with MVC5 and have gotten http `GET` and `POST` method constraints to work by adding the `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` attributes to my action methods. But when I add `[HttpPut]` I just get a 404 error page. Does anyone know what I need to do to get attribute routing working with http `PUT`? See code below:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("edit")]
    public ActionResult Edit() {
        // this works
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("insert")]
    public ActionResult Insert() {
        // this works
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [Route("update")]
    public ActionResult Update() {
        // this does not work
        return View();
    }
```

I've tried with `X-HTTP-Method-Override=PUT`

```
POST /update HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:61794
Content-Length: 32
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

X-HTTP-Method-Override=PUT&text=
```

And also with a real `PUT`

```
PUT /update HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:61794
Content-Length: 5
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

text=
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using [HttpPut] from System.Web.MVC? There is also [HttpPut] from System.Web.Http.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `System.Web.Mvc.HttpPutAttribute`.

Comment: Could you share how your request looks like? You can probably get the details from browser debugging tool or Fiddler...

Comment: Are you calling Update() in combination with HttpMethodOverride or do you send a real HttpPut (e.g. via ajax) request?

Comment: @Dresel I tried both X-HTTP-Method-Override and a real PUT. Both gives the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Real HttpPut**

This should work, but you have to modify the ExtensionlessUrlHandler to allow additional verbs:

```
<handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

**X-HTTP-Method-Override**

This seems to be a bug (or not just implemented) in 5.0. You could try a [nightly build](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Use%20Nightly%20Builds) of MVC 5.1 Alpha, where X-HTTP-Method-Override gets respected.

Comment: I just updated to the final version of MVC 5.1 and [HttpPut] works again :)