# HttpPut in Asp.net Mvc 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was trying to use "PUT" in my controller like

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPut]
        public ContentResult Test()
        {
            return Content("hi");
        }
    }
```

but I can't access it. I thought it was my code but after trying fiddler and getting the same error(404).

I think something else is up. I am just using iis express and mvc 5.

Before I never used HttpPut but been doing webapi lately so that's why I tried to do it in mvc 5 controller but I am not sure if in this case it bring me anything(especially with extra setup is needed as it seems like it is need)

[image]

Post request works

[image]

Comment: Are you making an HTTP PUT request?  If so, how are you making it?  I've got `[HttpPut]` being used in production so I know it works.

Comment: well I am using x-editable with "PUT" type and it did not work, then I used fiddler 2 with "PUT" and same thing get 404.

Comment: Can you show the full controller class and what the HTTP request that you're making looks like?

Comment: @chobo2 Is this action in an MVC or Web API controller? What is the controller's name? What is the URL path you're requesting?

Comment: That is an MVC Controller not a WebApi Controller

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to update the ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0.

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*"   type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

This solution can be found on:
[Attribute routing with http PUT method constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19811998/3193847)

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities for this failure. One is security, meaning that PUT header is being blocked:

Does your web server allow PUT headers? Try this:

```
...    
 <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <verbs>
                    <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
                </verbs>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
```

The other possibility is that your test is being subject to CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) and you may need to enable it in MVC. I have personally not done this MVC but only WebApi. I hope this link can help you:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/11609/how-to-enable-cross-origin-resource-sharing-in-mvc.aspx

Comment: Correct, Can you not use "PUt" with a regular controller, it is just a standard http request.

Comment: Well it is being ran locally through VS 2013 but I can try adding that to my web.config